# How to return the DTO of a dependency service when my contracts are defined in an Interface layer?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, domain-driven-design

I am using the Domain Driven Design approach to structure my RESTful web service in C# .NET 4.5 Web API solution with the following projects:

- WebApiUi (Controllers etc)
- BizApi (Content services etc)
- BizDomain (Business logic etc)
- DataAccessDB (Databases repositories, DALs etc)
- DataAccessSrvs (Dependency web service DALs etc)
- Interfaces (DTOs, class interfaces, etc)

The references in this solution generally work down that list, so every project references the Interfaces project while WebApiUi reference the BizX projects, which in turn reference the DataAccessX projects.

The DTOs returned by the web services access within the DataAccessSrvs project do not inherit the interfaces defined in the Interfaces project. This means that I cannot easily pass them back to the BisX layers or use them within the WebApiUi layer.

What is the best practice here? Should I unwrap them and repackage their data within DTOs which are fully defined in the Interfaces layer?

The web services are consumed using .NET generated client code.

Comment: What is "the DDD pattern" and how is this related to DDD at all?

Comment: Domain Driven Design. The use of the word pattern is probably ill-advised. Edited to reflect.

Comment: "The DTOs [...] do not inherit the interfaces defined in the Interfaces project." -- A DTO normally doesn't implement an interface, it's a simple data container with no behavior. Besides, you chose to introduce an additional `DataAccessSrvs` layer that returns objects fresh off the database. I guess there's a conversion taking place between these objects and Domain layer objects then. This might be overkill and I can't see any reason why these objects should be the same as the DTO's exchanged between BizX and UI layer.

Comment: The DTOs and C# interfaces happen to be contained within one project. The DTOs do not inherit any interfaces. The DataAccessSrvs project is for calling the web services which are a dependency of this solution, whereas the DataAccessDB project is for directly accessing the databases.

Comment: OK, I thought `DataAccessSrvs` talked to a database too. I'm not sure what you're really asking in the end, but I'd tend to use a Repository for converting external web service stuff to your Domain entities. Repository interfaces are usually defined in the Domain layer and concrete Repository implementations are in an Infrastructure layer (`DataAccessSrvs` ?). Infrastructure references Domain so no dependency problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to express my thoughts.

1. DTOs itself have not to inherit some interfaces. Interfaces have another semantic. Sometimes it is usefull to create base class for some DTO classes, but it is not recommended by some vendors (i.e. ServiceStack).
2. I see that talking about DTOs in your project is a little confusing. There are DTOs deinfing contract of your WebApiUi. Working with this kind of DTOs is just translating of domain model into returning DTO objects. According to DDD all your domain services and classes have to be described in terms of domain model. Thus domain model knowns nothing about service contract DTOs. All transformations are performed in WebApiUi controllers.
3. Another kind of DTOs is that ones you get from DataAccessSrvs. I recommend to use DataAccessSrvs to encapsulate knowledge about external services and transform external services DTOs into  domain model. So interface of DataAccessSrvs will be described in terms of domain. Thus cliens of such layer (BizDomain) knowns nothing about external service contracts.

With this considerations I propose

### 1.

```
[WebApiUi] -> [DTOs], [BizDomain + Interfaces]

[BizDomain + Interfaces]

[DataAccessSrvs] -> [DTOs], [BizDomain + Interfaces]
```

in this schema [BizDomain] classes uses [DataAccessSrvs] via [Interfaces] (classic Dependency Inversion), but [BizDomain + Interfaces] contain interfaces only for some 'shared' between domain model and [DataAccessSrvs] interfaces, just to implement dependency inversion. [BizDomain + Interfaces] has no relations to some service contracts and DTOs.

### 2.

For better maintainability I would recommend to split WebApiUi' DTOs from DataAccessSrvs's DTOs:

```
[WebApiUi] -> [MyDTOs], [BizDomain + Interfaces]

[BizDomain + Interfaces]

[DataAccessSrvs] -> [ExternalDTOs], [BizDomain + Interfaces]
```